# Submit unsigned pkcs10 to windows certificate authority

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

Is it possible to make a Windows Server Certificate Authority accept a PKCS10 certificate request that is unsigned? I get the following error `Error Verifying Request Signature or Signing Certificate  The request is not supported. 0x80070032 (WIN32: 50 ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)`. I would like for the CA to skip the signature check and just accept the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Microsoft ADCS does not support requests without a single trusted signature. That is, the request must be signed directly (signature is created by requester) or by external signers. In this case, a PKCS#10 request must be embedded in PKCS#7/CMC request and signed with authorized signing certificate.

With CertEnroll you can utilize [IX509CertificateRequestCmc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377133(v=vs.85).aspx) COM interface:

1. load existing unsigned request to `IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10` interface
2. load PKCS10 request to `IX509CertificateRequestCmc` interface by using `InitializeFromInnerRequestTemplateName` method
3. use `IX509CertificateRequestCmc::SignerCertificates` to provide external signer information (certificate)
4. load CMC request into `IX509Enrollment` interface
5. call `IX509Enrollment::CreateRequest` to sign and create signed request.

By the end, you will get a signed CMC request with embedded unsigned PKCS#10 request and which you can submit to CA server.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. By "authorised signing certificate" do you mean the certificate of an entity that is trusted by the CA (say, a RA/sub-CA)?

Comment: Signer is entity who owns signing certificate which is suitable for external request signing. Signing certificate must be trusted by CA and signer entity is eligible to request certificates against a template specified in the `InitializeFromInnerRequestTemplateName` method call.

Comment: I tried to follow your guide, but I keep on getting the error "Error Verifying Request Signature or Signing Certificate  The request is not supported. 0x80070032 (WIN32: 50 ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)". If you could point me in the right direction as to what is going on it would be much appreciated! Here's the code I used (.NET): https://pastebin.com/uhHeARgC

Comment: Can you post the outpur of the following command: `certutil -dump path\reqfile.req`?

Comment: Here is the dump: https://pastebin.com/S9Z4GX8a I actually got a different error by trying a different approach with the code: "Error Verifying Request Signature or Signing Certificate  The certificate is not valid for the requested usage. 0x800b0110 (-2146762480 CERT_E_WRONG_USAGE)". The code that generated this error is here: https://pastebin.com/BTVugNHV

Comment: I could have misunderstood you, did you want the .req file I'm using to Submit() to the CA? This is the correct dump: https://pastebin.com/w4q1QHde

Comment: The dump is not from the request you are creating. Can you run the certutil command against request file you are creating with your code?

Comment: Sorry, updated: https://pastebin.com/w4q1QHde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77804/discussion-between-crypt32-and-ivan-stanev).

Comment: a bit of a late continuation but was hoping you could shed some light on this... I can successfully issue certificates but authentication is acting really weird. Whenever I provide any credentials or set the CX509CertificateRequestCmc's RequesterName, my CA accepts it only if it's in the "DOMAIN\Username" format. It will reject the request if the full domain is given as "full.domain.name\Username". I thought the format "DOMAIN\Username" is an old way to provide user credentials. Does that mean that the newer format is unsupported by the API?

Comment: If you want to use FQDN in authentication, you should use UPN format. This allows you to specify full domain name. Name with slashes always was intended for pre-Windows 2000 NetBIOS name.